# Command prompt hanging

Tags: c#

I have made a program which backs up a Storage Account on Azure. To do this I am using AzCopy. I have 4 containers in my storage account and I do a `foreach` through my Storage account to get all containers. My first container is backed up fine. When the backup is completed I want to move to the next item (container) in the `foreach` the command prompt just hangs. Not sure why this is happening.

My code is as follows for my foreach

```
public static string strCommand= @"C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SDKs\Azure\AzCopy";

foreach (CloudBlobContainer items in sourcepslFileStoreContainers)
{
    containerCount = 0;
    if (items.Exists() && dayBlob.Exists())
    {
        // full backup using AzCopy
        if (dayBlob.Name == "day5" || dayBlob.Name == "day15")
        {
            var AzCopyProcess = new ProcessStartInfo()
            {
                FileName = "cmd.exe",
                RedirectStandardInput = true,
                RedirectStandardOutput = true,
                UseShellExecute = false,
                WindowStyle = ProcessWindowStyle.Normal
            };

            var process = new Process { StartInfo = AzCopyProcess };

            process.Start();
            process.StandardInput.WriteLine($@"cd {strCommand}");
            Console.WriteLine("Found directory");
            process.StandardInput.WriteLine($@"AzCopy.exe");
            Console.WriteLine("Found exe");
            process.StandardInput.WriteLine($"AzCopy /Source:{pslFileStore.Uri} /Dest:{dayBlob.Uri} /SourceKey:{pslFileStoreKey.ToString()} /DestKey:{pslFileStoreBackUpKey.ToString()} /S");
            //process.BeginOutputReadLine();
            process.StandardOutput.ReadToEnd();
            process.WaitForExit();
            process.Close();
            Console.WriteLine($"Backed up ");
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: `WaitForExit` is waiting for `cmd.exe` to exit - after all, that's the process you started and is represented by `process` - not `AzCopy`. And you've not done anything to cause `cmd` to exit. Why are you working via `cmd` rather than directly invoking `AzCopy`?

Comment: @Damien_The_Unbeliever are you saying I should have AzCopy.exe as my Filename instead? I'm running cmd because all the instructions I give it is using the command prompt

Comment: @Damien_The_Unbeliever this seems to be an ever recurring pattern or is it just me? There have been several nearly exact same questions in the last few days. "Same" in that cmd.exe was used instead of the actual program that was intended to run.

Comment: @CraigGallagher - yes, I'd expect the `WorkingDirectory` to be `strCommand`, the `FileName` to be `AzCopy.exe` and the `Arguments` to be `/Source...`.

Comment: @Fildor - yes, we seem to be seeing this same bizarre pattern recurring. I'd guess I'm seeing one or two examples like this each day at the moment.

Comment: @Damien_The_Unbeliever could you please give me an example of the `Arguments`if you don't mind